# Installing Git on a Linux VM (RHEL)

Tags: linux, git

We need to set up a Git server in our team.

I have decided to first go with a VM, and expand in the future if needed.

I've gathered Linux would be the easiest setup.

Problem is, i have very limited experience with Linux, some questions that i'm trying to answer are:

1. What is the actual procedure for installing the Git package? is it a simple matter of RPM installation ?
2. Following the installation, i'd need to map the Git repo to some net share. how is this done? i believe that i need to configure xinetd.d, looking for exact steps.
3. How is authentication is set up for various users to access this machine?
4. Which version of Linux makes any difference? we have the RHEL 5 64 bit here.
5. Anything else i'm currently missing?

Comment: I do not think this is programming related. More likely server administrators from serverfault can help better

Answer (score 1):

1. Haven't used RHEL 5 but yes, any modern distro should have git available in a package. I'm guessing that "yum install git" would do it.
2. Depends on the type of net share. Google it.
3. See http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way
4. Shouldn't.